# wrap content in a div and then appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to wrap `appendcontent` into `image` div, but got [object Object] returned.

```
 $("<div class=image>" + appendcontent + "</div>").appendTo($('.outside'));
```

How to put `$(appendcontent)`  inside  `$("<div class=image></div>" )`

online sample 
http://jsfiddle.net/PYQXa/5/

I know I can use `html()` but if I put html(), the slider won't work. that is the reason I need to keep the object.

Comment: Can you include an example of what `appendcontent` is? Is it a text string? html?

Comment: appendcontent is a jquery object.  Maybe you're looking for appendcontent.html()?

Comment: if I make it html(), the slider won't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.append`:

```
$('<div class="image">').append(appendcontent).appendTo('.outside');
```

Or `.wrap`:

```
appendcontent.wrap('<div class="image">').appendTo('.outside');
```

It's also a common practice to prefix variables that contain jQuery objects with `$` (e.g. `$appendcontent`).

Answer (score 1):

Some changes here:

- Wrap your class inside quotes `' '` or double quotes `" "`
- You need to use `appendcontent.html()` instead of `appendcontent` since appendcontent is a jQuery object:
- Use `appendTo('.outside')` instead of `appendTo($('.outside'))`

So it look like this:

```
$("<div class='outside'>" + appendcontent.html() + "</div>").appendTo('.outside');
```

---

You can use `append()` then `appendTo()` instead:

```
$('<div class="image">').append(appendcontent).appendTo('.outside');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PYQXa/7/)**

Comment: Thanks! But if I make it html(), the slider won't work  http://jsfiddle.net/PYQXa/6/

Comment: @olo: BTW, you can obviously name vars however you please, but pre-pending var names with `$` usually implies a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

I created jsfiddle here

```
 http://jsfiddle.net/j5jdb/
```

jQuery

```
var $inside = $('.inside');
//$inside.hide();
var appendcontent = $inside.find('.slider').html();
//$(appendcontent).appendTo($('.outside'));

// $("<div class=outside>" + appendcontent + "</div>").appendTo($('.outside'));


// settings
var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
var $transition_time = 1000; // 1 second
var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

function slides(){
  return $slider.find($slide);
}

slides().fadeOut();

// set active classes
slides().first().addClass('active');
slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

// auto scroll 
$interval = setInterval(
    function(){
      var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

      slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
      slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

      if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

      slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
      slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
    }
    , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
);
```